# price of dsp kit TMS320c6678(used for signal processing)

Tags: audio-processing

This kit is used for implementing DSP concets in hardware
What is the meaning of highlighted price in attached fig?
Does it means 120 dollar per unit chip price?[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWfpL.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this stack exchange board has Digital Signal Processing as its main topic.

Comment: It's not the price for the kit, it's the price for the DSP chip bought in a certain quantity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you buy at least 1000 units, each will cost you 120